# Apache Flink RabbitMq SBT dependency failing

Tags: sbt, rabbitmq, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to use Flink with RabbitMq streaming connector. Tried all possible combinations of version and still failing.

Here is my sbt build snippet

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.7"

val flinkVersion = "1.0.0"

val json4sNative = "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.3.0"

val flinkDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion %     "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-rabbitmq" % "0.10.1",
  json4sNative)
```

Snippet of error

```
[error] (root/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryConfigurationError.class
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryConfigurationError.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$1.class
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$1.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinder.class
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinder.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete.class
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder.class
[error] /Users/gopigrip7/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error]
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try build with same Flink dependencies version? I succeeded the build (`sbt assembly`) with following SBT configuration:

```
name := "flink-sbt-sample"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

val flinkVersion = "1.0.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-rabbitmq" % flinkVersion,
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.3.0"
)
```

Note that there is a guide for Flink project with SBT (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/quickstart/scala_api_quickstart.html#sbt).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried and  failed. I moved to mvn and could able to compile.